How to create table view in SwiftUI?
How do I implement a view in SwiftUI similar to the table below? The table is scrollable vertically and horizontally, able to sort it using any of the columns and when clicked on row, it opens another view with details.

The image is from an app called Thinkorswim which is a broker for trading stocks. The spark chart column can be ignored.
E.g. Here's an example of table view I'm been trying using Table view, however, it only displays single column on iOS platform. The documentation for Table specifies "You can define a single table for use on macOS, iOS, and iPadOS. However, in a compact horizontal size class environment — typical on iPhone or on iPad in certain modes, like Slide Over — the table has limited space to display its columns. To conserve space, the table automatically hides headers and all columns after the first when it detects this condition"
I'm aware I can implement separate logic for compat case to display information in single column, but I'd like to explore option where I can have multiple columns and have them scrollable.
struct TickerDetails: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let ticker: String
    let price: Double
    let percChange: Double
    let volume: Int
}

struct TableViewExample: View {
    @State var tickers = [TickerDetails(ticker: "AAPL", price: 100.0, percChange: 1.2, volume: 4_500_000),
                          TickerDetails(ticker: "AMZN", price: 180.0, percChange: 2.5, volume: 6_000_000),
                          TickerDetails(ticker: "NVDA", price: 130.0, percChange: 5.2, volume: 7_500_000)]
    var body: some View {
        Table(tickers) {
            TableColumn("Ticker", value: \.ticker)
            TableColumn("Mark") { ticker in
                Text(String(ticker.price))
            }
            TableColumn("Mark %") { ticker in
                Text(String(ticker.percChange))
            }
            TableColumn("Volume") { ticker in
                Text(String(ticker.volume))
            }
        }
    }
}


Thanks!

One of the lazy grids or Grid, there is no build in tool for it.

You could do what you want with a Table, TableColumns, and a sortOrder that the user can change by tapping in different columns in a header, but it would require a fair amount of manual work.
This article explains most of what you need to do to create a Table with multiple columns. You'd have to enhance it to add graphical columns, and build a mechanism for the user to switch the column that's used for sorting.
You could also achieve what you want with a Grid or LazyGrid, as mentioned by Lorem Ipsum in their comment.
